# Can't access public textBox7 created in form1, while in form2

Tags: c#

I have a textbox7 created in form1, but I want to access it in another form, form 2 so I changed its modifiers to public

When I get on form2 i want it to perform the following

```
Form1.textBox7.ReadOnly = true;
```

but I get the following error

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.textBox7' C:\Users\Admin\Google
>   Drive\AdminhomeGD\ztese\zprograma\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\formOpConfig.cs   73  46  WindowsFormsApplication1

i have no idea what's wrong

Edit:

I'm trying to use the following, on form1 (named Form1):

```
        public Boolean gammamanual
    {
        get { return textBox7.ReadOnly; }
        set { textBox7.ReadOnly = value; }
    }
```

while on form2 (named formOpConfig):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class formOpConfig : Form


{

   public formOpConfig(Form1 opener)
{
    // this is a constructor
    this.Opener = opener;
}

private Form1 Opener { get; set; }

public formOpConfig() { // initialization and stuff }

private void buttonExit_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
if (checkBox3.Checked == true) { this.textBox7.gammamanual = false; } 
else {   this.textBox7.gammamanual = true; }
this.Hide();
}
```

I want it so that when the checkbox3 is checked and the form2 exited, the textBox7 will be editable manualy.

Edit:2 the problem was that form2 was started from form1, also, i had 2 different constructors in form2 (formOpConfig). the solution was adapting the main constructor using

```
   private Form1 Opener { get; set; }



    public formOpConfig(Form1 opener)
    {

        this.Opener = opener;
        InitializeComponent(); //Stuff
    }
```

meanwhile i was able to start formOpConfig from the Form1 using

```
formOpConfig painelconfig = new formOpConfig(this);
        painelconfig.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Have you ever search on your message in Google? I think you will find a lot or results.

Comment: Maybe you should learn a bit more about C# and static members. And about code design, because what you're trying to do is awful.

Comment: actually someone here recommended that process.. and i used other variables that way, and they are working correctly, it only doesnt work when it's a textbox.

Comment: I think that person should be fired...

Comment: @Patrick Hofman sorry if not everyone here is a professional, at least he tried to help. Everyone else, please refrain from making negative comments, no matter how bad you think the question was a lot of professionals in other areas than coding make useful programs, and these questions are a part of it.

Comment: @Cesar: I don't think you should be fired, but the one recommending this kind of bad behavior. It violates every design guideline. In contrary, you posted a decent question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access an instance variable via class name, that works only if it's static. So you need an instance of `Form1` to access a property/field of it. You could for example pass it via constructor from `Form1` to `Form2`(if `Form1` instantiates `Form2`) or use a property/method.

But instead of exposing the complete control i would only provide what is necessary, that's called [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). You could expose a public property with a meaningful name that describes the purpose of `textBox7`(change also this name). Presuming it's purpose is to show a username the property could be `UserName`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get{return TxtUserName.Text;}
        set{ TxtUserName.Text = value;}
    }
    // ...
}
```

Since you want to get/set the `ReadOnly` property of the `TextBox` you could provide another property:

```
public bool UserNameEditable
{
    get{ return !TxtUserName.ReadOnly; }
    set{ TxtUserName.ReadOnly = !value; }
}
```

Now you are able to get/set it from another `Form` if you have an instance of `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Form1 opener)
    {
        // this is a constructor
        this.Opener = opener;
    }

    private Form1 Opener { get; set; }

    private void SomeMethod() 
    {
        this.Opener.UserName = "Tim";
        this.Opener.UserNameEditable = false;
    }
    // ...
}
```

You need to pass the `Form1` instance to the constructor of `Form2` when you instantiate it. Another approach is to make the property `Opener` public and use that which suffers the disadvantage that you cannot be sure that it was set.

Another approach is using LINQ and [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is elegant but error-prone:

```
var form1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
form1.UserName = "Tim";
```

Side-note: `Form1` and `Form2` are also crying for more meaningful names.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand it all so i tried to make some changes in edit, what i can't grasp is, how do i define that i want textbox7, and not anyother textbox to get the correct value. I made a edition on that, do you mind taking a look?

Comment: @CésarAmorim: instead of `this.textBox7.gammamanual = false;` you have to use your `Opener` property which is the `Form1` that has the textbox: `this.Opener.gammamanual = false;`. Note that properties should be pascal-case so `GammaManual`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i tried that also and the program runs, but when i check the box and exit form2 i get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exactly on `this.Opener.gammamanual = false;`  @Tim

Comment: @CésarAmorim: have you also the default constructor in `formOpConfig`? Then i guess that you have used that to instantiate the second from instead of the new constructor. Remove the default constructor since it's a source of errors like this. **Edit** yes, you have still that constructor without parameter here: `public formOpConfig() { // initialization and stuff }`

Comment: from your answer i had the constructor in formOpConfig, and not on Form1, anyways i tried to remove it from formOpConfig, but the same error remains, this is pretty complex for a beginner but i think i'm close to make it work

Comment: @CésarAmorim: you have two constructors in `formOpConfig`, one without a parameter and our new with the opener-parameter. If you remove the default constructor you ensure that evenbody who is using this form is forced to provide the `Form1` instance. But you could also use my last approach using `Application.OpenForms`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52211/discussion-between-cesar-amorim-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `form1` instance and make a public property to set the control within `form1`.

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{       
    private Form1 objForm1;      

    public Form2(Form1 frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //get other form
        this.objForm1= frm;

        //call here public property of form1 which set controls properties within form1
        this.objForm1.SetReadOnly = true;
     }
}
```

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //setter Property
    public bool SetReadOnly
    {           
       set{ this.TextBox7.ReadOnly= value;}
       get{ return this.TextBox7.ReadOnly;}
    }

    //Form1 Constructor
    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();      
    } 

    //Form1 Load
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a form, the controls are created with a private access modifier (see the designer code).

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
```

Therefore, these controls are not accessible from another form. What you should do is create a public or internal property on your form.

```
public TextBox TextBox7 { get { return textBox7; } }
```

Once you created an instance of Form1 in (an instance of) Form2, you can access this property.

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.TextBox7.ReadOnly = true;
```